# Inserting into document elasticsearch java API not working

Tags: java, elasticsearch

So I am just trying to add data in my `indice` via `java transport client api` . My code runs without any exceptions.

- It successfully connects to my server, I can see the connection details on my console.
- I listed all `indices` available on the server and it did show that too.
- Then I tried to insert `docs` into my `indice` called `logs`
- code runs without any exceptions.

> I am lost here and have no idea what I am missing. The data is not getting inserted in the `indice`. Any help is appreciated.

Below is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        ElasticSearchMain es  = new ElasticSearchMain();
        ElasticSearchMain.configureClient();
        JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
        data.put("serverip", "bhavik");
        data.put("classname", "bhavik");
        data.put("methodname", "bhavik");
        data.put("exception", "bhavik");
        data.put("logexception", "4896681231231232");
        data.put("timestamp", "1900-00-00");


        es.setIndex(data.toString(), "logs");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public IndexRequestBuilder setIndex(String data,String IndexName){
        try{
            return client.prepareIndex(IndexName, "event").setSource(data);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }


public static void configureClient(){

        try{

            if(client==null){
                String address = "localhost";

                int port = 9300;
                BasicConfigurator.configure();
                client = TransportClient.builder().build()
                        .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName(address), port));

                String[] indices = client.admin().indices().getIndex(new GetIndexRequest()).actionGet().getIndices();
                for (String s : indices) {
                    System.out.println("indice ->> " + s);
                }

            }


        }catch(Exception e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
            EmgrLog.AppendExceptionToLog(e);
        }
    }
```

Indice mapping :

```
PUT logs
{
   "mappings": {
      "event": {
         "properties": {
            "serverip": {
               "type": "integer",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "classname": {
               "type": "string",
               "analyzer": "english"
            },
            "methodname": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "exception": {
               "type": "string",
               "index": "not_analyzed"
            },
            "logexception": {
               "type": "string"
            },
            "timestamp":{
                "type": "date"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code :

```
public IndexRequestBuilder setIndex(String data,String IndexName){
    try{
        return client.prepareIndex(IndexName, "event").setSource(data);
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Returns a "request builder", but this request is never built, nor executed, and logically, nothing happens as a consequence.

To submit the request, you have to send it to the elasticsearch instance.

[Elasticsearch JavaAPI documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-docs-index.html) proposes this code :

```
IndexResponse response = client.prepareIndex("twitter", "tweet", "1")
    .setSource(jsonBuilder()
                .startObject()
                    .field("user", "kimchy")
                    .field("postDate", new Date())
                    .field("message", "trying out Elasticsearch")
                .endObject()
              )
    .get();
```

Note the `get()` at the end of the snippet is what triggers the call.

Comment: aaah! i knew i was missing something stupid. Thank you for your explanation.!